# nested for loop in R not producing the correct amount of iterations

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

I have a pretty simple for loop (or so I thought). The purpose of it is to do an action 1000 times under 20 different conditions. This should provide a result of 20,000. Instead I get 1000. My thinking is that I am likely missing something pretty trivial.

```
nSims <- 1000
Prop1 <- numeric(nSims * 20) 
Prop2 <- numeric(nSims * 20) 
Prop3 <- numeric(nSims * 20)
Score <- NA

for(i in 1:nSims){
for (j in 1:20){
G1 <- rnorm (10000, 100, 10)
G2 <- rnorm (10000, 100 - i/50, 10)
G3 <- rnorm (10000, 100 + i/50, 10)

Prop1 [i] = length (which (G1 > (100+j))) /length (G1)
Prop2 [i] = length (which (G2 > (100+j))) /length (G2)
Prop3 [i] = length (which (G3 > (100+j))) /length (G3)
Score [j] = 100 + j
}
}
sim <- data.frame (cbind (Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Score))
```

The output should be a dataframe with three variable of 1000 for each iteration of j. Instead, I get 50 iterations of J and then a lot of 0's.

Comment: You are re-assigning, and replacing, Prop1 [i], Prop2[i]... for every `j` iteration,

Comment: @GuedesBF you are right. What should I do to not reassign? Just add the props outside and have sim [j]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a different index (`k`) to save the calculation.

```
nSims <- 1000
Prop1 <- numeric(nSims * 20) 
Prop2 <- numeric(nSims * 20) 
Prop3 <- numeric(nSims * 20)
Score <- NA
k <- 0

for(i in 1:nSims){
  for (j in 1:20){
    G1 <- rnorm (10000, 100, 10)
    G2 <- rnorm (10000, 100 - i/50, 10)
    G3 <- rnorm (10000, 100 + i/50, 10)
    k <- k + 1
    Prop1 [k] = length (which (G1 > (100+j))) /length (G1)
    Prop2 [k] = length (which (G2 > (100+j))) /length (G2)
    Prop3 [k] = length (which (G3 > (100+j))) /length (G3)
    Score [k] = 100 + j
  }
}
sim <- data.frame (Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Score)

nrow(sim)
#[1] 20000
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that you could have a different index within your sim to store the calculations. I thought the indices had to be tied to the iterations.